# Flatness of Formal Power Series

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

According to Matsumura's Commutative Ring Theory, Ex. 7.4, the direct product of flat modules over a Noetherian ring $A$ is flat. How can we use this result to conclude that the formal power series in $n$ variables over $A$ is flat? Can we think of the formal power series as the direct product of infinite copies of $A$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course. Although $A[[x]]$ and $A^{\mathbb{N}}$ are not isomorphic as rings, they are isomorphic as $A$-modules, essentially by definition.

Comment: Also, $A[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ is flat by a similar argument. Correct?

Comment: Yes (also in case you mean $A[[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]]$).